# JQuery and table

Tags: jquery, html

I am struggling with jquery toggle function.

I tried in different ways of coding, but have not found a solution yet.

It should be slide down when I press ZZZZ in the table.

Also, css format for the table does not apply to ZZZZ아반떼 AD강남지점-강남지점.

What I am wondering is why css id for tablemain does not apply to second data set.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tableMain').on('click', 'tr.breakrow', function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.breakrow').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 850px;
  /*height: 500px;*/
  /*height:500px;*/
  /*color:white;*/
  /*margin-top:50px;*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

hr.garo {
  border: 1px solid #757272;
  margin: 5px 0px -10px 0px;
}

#tableMain {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

th {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  color: white;
}

.page {
  background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#pop {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left
}

img {
  width: 350px;
}

#bor {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.pay {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.418);
}

.search {
  background: #ffc107;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>차량이용내역</title>
<div class="outer">
  <span class="title">차량이용 내역</span>
  <hr class="garo">
  <br><br>

  <button class="search" type="submit">사용자 지정</button>

  <table id="tableMain">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>이용기간</th>
        <th>차종</th>
        <th>지점명</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="breakrow">
        <td>ZZZZ</td>
        <td>아반떼 AD</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <table style="border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse;">
          <tbody>
            <tr id="pop">
              <td id="bor" rowspan="2" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">
                <td id="bor">대여일</td>
                <td id="bor">2020년 02월 05일 09:00</td>
                <td id="bor">대여 위치</td>
                <td id="bor">강남지점</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="pop">
              <td id="bor">반납일</td>
              <td id="bor"> 2020년 02월 07일 14:00 </td>
              <td id="bor">반납 위치 </td>
              <td id="bor">강남지점</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">아반떼AD/휘발유(145허3271)</td>
              <td class="pay" colspan="3">총결제 금액</td>
              <td class="pay">245,800원</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </tr>

      <tr class="breakrow">
        <td>ZZZZ</td>
        <td>아반떼 AD</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <table style="border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse;">
          <tbody>
            <tr id="pop">
              <td id="bor" rowspan="2" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">
                <td id="bor">대여일</td>
                <td id="bor">2020년 02월 05일 09:00</td>
                <td id="bor">대여 위치</td>
                <td id="bor">강남지점</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="pop">
              <td id="bor">반납일</td>
              <td id="bor"> 2020년 02월 07일 14:00 </td>
              <td id="bor">반납 위치 </td>
              <td id="bor">강남지점</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">아반떼AD/휘발유(145허3271)</td>
              <td class="pay" colspan="3">총결제 금액</td>
              <td class="pay">245,800원</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </tr>



    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Not the question you asked, but note that HTML doesn't allow a `tr` to "slide".  There are ways around it (put a div inside the tr and slide that) but `$("tr").slideToggle()` doesn't "slide".  Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4uhjtwnz/

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your HTML. Inspect the snippet in the dev tools of your browser and you see that there is no next tr with the class `breakdown`

Fix these errors and your script should work.

Answer (score 0):

John you were directly enclosing the table in **tr** which is not allowed, you need to enclosed it in **td**, check the code snippet below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>차량이용내역</title>
<style>
    .outer{
        width:850px;
        /*height: 500px;*/
        /*height:500px;*/
        /*color:white;*/
        /*margin-top:50px;*/
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }

    .title{
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:900;
    }

    hr.garo {
        border: 1px solid #757272;
        margin: 5px 0px -10px 0px;
    }

    #tableMain{
        width:800px;
        border:1px solid lightgray;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing:0px;
        margin-top:40px;
    }

    th{
        margin-top: 10px;
        background: lightgray;
    }

    th,td {
         padding: 15px 20px;
         text-align: center;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    a:hover{
        background-color: #ffc107;
        color:white;

    }

    .page{
        background-color:rgb(244, 244, 244);
        margin-top: 50px;
        color: black;
        border-radius:5px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #pop{
        border: 1px solid gray;
        font-size: 10px;
        text-align:left
    }

    img{
        width:350px;
    }

    #bor{
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }

    .pay{
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.418);
    }

    .search{
        background: #ffc107;
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
        width: 80px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        float:right;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
    </style>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', 'tr.breakrow',function(){ 
            $(this).closest('tr').next("tr").slideToggle();
        });
    });
    </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer"> 
            <span class="title">차량이용 내역</span>
            <hr class="garo">
            <br><br>

            <button class="search" type="submit">사용자 지정</button>

            <table id="tableMain">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>이용기간</th>
                          <th>차종</th>
                          <th>지점명</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                                <tr class="breakrow"><td>ZZZZ</td><td>아반떼 AD</td><td>강남지점-강남지점</td></tr>
                                <tr> 
         <td colspan="3">
                                      <table style="border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                      <tbody>
                                            <tr id="pop"><td id="bor" rowspan="2" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg"><td id="bor">대여일</td><td id="bor">2020년 02월 05일 09:00</td><td id="bor">대여 위치</td><td id="bor">강남지점</td></tr>
                                            <tr id="pop"><td id="bor">반납일</td><td id="bor"> 2020년 02월 07일 14:00 </td><td id="bor">반납 위치 </td><td id="bor">강남지점</td></tr>
                                              <tr><td colspan="2">아반떼AD/휘발유(145허3271)</td><td class="pay" colspan="3">총결제 금액</td><td class="pay">245,800원</td></tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                          </table>
            </td>
                                  </tr> 

                                  <tr class="breakrow"><td>ZZZZ</td><td>아반떼 AD</td><td>강남지점-강남지점</td></tr>
                                <tr>  
         <td colspan="3">
                                      <table style="border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                      <tbody>
                                            <tr id="pop"><td id="bor" rowspan="2" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg"><td id="bor">대여일</td><td id="bor">2020년 02월 05일 09:00</td><td id="bor">대여 위치</td><td id="bor">강남지점</td></tr>
                                            <tr id="pop"><td id="bor">반납일</td><td id="bor"> 2020년 02월 07일 14:00 </td><td id="bor">반납 위치 </td><td id="bor">강남지점</td></tr>
                                              <tr><td colspan="2">아반떼AD/휘발유(145허3271)</td><td class="pay" colspan="3">총결제 금액</td><td class="pay">245,800원</td></tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                          </table>
            </td>
                                  </tr> 

                    </tbody>
                </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will serve your purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much your help. I understand all the comments above, but I am pretty new to coding. Sadly, I could not apply... this helped me a lot and served my purpose. Thank you!

Comment: You can now copy the above code snippet, hope it will server your purpose! And if so please mark the above answer useful.